# WooCommerce mini cart empty on homepage

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

In my WooCommerce shop I make use of the mini cart. It works as it should works, when I add a product it shows (1), perfect. The problem I am facing is that when I have added a product and go to the index page, it shows (0). Product is in the mini cart because when I go to another page, it appears back as (1). This problem I have with 2 other pages and only in the browser safari. Google chrome works fine.

Hoping for some suggestion to test or solutions.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you share website url?

Comment: I can't I am sorry. I think I've figured out the problem. It seems when you come on the website, page has been cached by w3c total cache. This cache seems to be really strict for some pages. When I disable this plugin, it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: Glad you have solved your problem.